# Using Excel Online to open an excel workbook sent as a link from email

Tags: asp.net-mvc, excel

I am writing an excel task pane app for invoicing and payment. Once a new invoice is created i save it to onedrive using onedrive live API's. For this I have written code in ASP.NET MVC. After saving this invoice to onedrive i get a hyperlink which is the location of my invoice stored on onedrive. Also i have written code which copies this link and adds it in an email that is sent to the customer. When we click on this link received from email, the invoice does not opens up using excel online but it asks whether we want to download it to local machine and then opens usind excel in our desktop. What do i need to do if i want this invoice to open using excel online in the browser itself when i click on the hyperlink received inside the email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using WL.api to pass the path of the file stored on onedrive, i could obtain a url. When i put that url as a link inside the email that i was sending to the client client gets successful in opening the excel invoice using excel online.

Answer (score 0):

Just append the url to the link.

- **Google Docs Viewer**

Just append the url od document you want to display
http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://online.verypdf.com/examples/pdfeditor.pdf

- **VeryPdf**

http://online.verypdf.com/api/?apikey=XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX&app=ViewAsPDFPaper&infile=http://spreadsheetpage.com/downloads/xl/time%20sheet.xls

**EDIT** 
Try this link: 
https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://spreadsheetpage.com/downloads/xl/time%2520sheet.xls

Hope it may help you. Have anice day. :)

Comment: Hi Pratik,I tried doing what you suggested above. It opens the document using google docs whereas my concern is opening it through excel online.

Comment: Nope...Still opens using google docs and not excel online. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Hold on, you want to use Excel Online. Any specific reason ?

Comment: SRS dictates to use excel online nothing else.

Comment: User who is going to open the document, is he going to open it from his personal one drive account or from a common shared file, which can be viewed by any one

Comment: User is going to open the document from the shared file on onedrive. This will be onedrive accound of the one who has created and saved the document and sent it to the user as a hyperlink for payment via email.